# Move .txt files into subdirectories

Tags: bash

I have multiple directories in a single directory.

```
Astrocytes_BloodCells_GeneSet/   Astrocytes_Polydendrocytes_GeneSet/  Endothelia_Neurons_GeneSet/   Microglia.y_Neurons_GeneSet/           Oligodendrocytes_Microglia.y_GeneSet/      Polydendrocytes_Microglia.x_GeneSet/
Astrocytes_Endothelia_GeneSet/   BloodCells_Endothelia_GeneSet/       Microglia.x_BloodCells_GeneSet/   Oligodendrocytes_Astrocytes_GeneSet/   Oligodendrocytes_Neurons_GeneSet/      Polydendrocytes_Microglia.y_GeneSet/
Astrocytes_Microglia.x_GeneSet/  BloodCells_Microglia.y_GeneSet/      Microglia.x_Endothelia_GeneSet/   Oligodendrocytes_BloodCells_GeneSet/   Oligodendrocytes_Polydendrocytes_GeneSet/  Polydendrocytes_Neurons_GeneSet/
Astrocytes_Microglia.y_GeneSet/
```

Each of these subdirectories contains a folder that follows the format:

```
_.LD_RESULTS_directoryname
```

for example, `Astrocytes_BloodCells_GeneSet/` contains a folder called `_.LD_RESULTS_Astrocytes_BloodCells_GeneSet/`, and so on. Inside these directories are multiple .txt files.

I am trying to write a simple script that copies the .txt inside `Astrocytes_BloodCells_GeneSet/,Astrocytes_Polydendrocytes_GeneSet/` etc... into the `_.LD_RESULTS_directoryname` folders. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you provide the output of `tree` and an example of what you would like the output of `tree` to look like after the move operation?

Comment: Did you mean, for the example, to say that the subfolder was `_.LD_RESULTS_Astrocytes_BloodCells_GeneSet` instead of `...Endothelia...`?

Comment: That was a typo, corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have a top directory,where you have only these directories, I think the following shellscript can both create the `_.LD_RESULTS_` subdirectories if necessary and do to copying.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in */
do
 target="$i/_.LD_RESULTS_$i"
 mkdir -p "$target"
 cp -p "${i}"*.txt "$target"
done
```

Are you sure that you want copies? An alternative is to move the files. If you want a backup, it should be in another drive (to survive a drive crash).

Answer (score 1):

If the _.LD_RESULTS directory names contain the parent directory name exactly, then this `for` loop should do the trick:

```
for dir in *_*_GeneSet
do
  echo cp "$dir"/*.txt "$dir"/_.LD_RESULTS_"$dir"/
done
```

I used a pattern for the `for` loop's wildcard that requires "anything", underscore, "anything", underscore, "GeneSet" as the parent directory name. Adjust that to widen or narrow the scope as needed.